# How to find the reduced cost of a variable in a large data set

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, network-flow

I have been given a large data set with a list of starting nodes, their destination nodes, and the length to each destination node from each starting node. Using Dijkstra's algorithm, I coded a shortest path problem for the data set, but now I am being asked "what is the reduced cost of the flow variable $x_{1, 72}$ where the length between nodes 1 and 72 is 21.

How do I found what the reduced cost is and what does it mean? I thought the reduced cost would be 21 since that is the cost that the path increases by by going through those two nodes, but I don't think that is right. How does the optimal value change if we change the length between those nodes to 10 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c_{ij}$ be the original arc cost of variable $x_{ij}$, and let $\pi_i$ be the dual variable for node $i$.  The reduced cost of variable $x_{ij}$ is $c_{ij}-\pi_i+\pi_j$.  The interpretation is that (assuming nondegeneracy) the reduced cost is the amount of improvement in the objective value per unit decrease of $c_{ij}$ if all other arc costs stay the same.

Comment: How do I find what the pi values are? I am assuming in this case that x_ij means length so x_ij= 21 currently?

Comment: No, $c_{ij}$ is the length, and $x_{ij}$ is $1$ for arcs in the shortest path. The dual variables $\pi_i$ represent the shortest path distances.

Comment: To clarify, $c_{ij}$ is the length of arc $(i,j)$, and $\pi_i$ is the length of a shortest path from the source node to node $i$.